# Simple joi schema using when does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I expect the following to print an error:

```
var joi = require('joi');

var schema = {
  role_type: joi.string(),
  info: {
    address: joi.object({
      postal_code: joi.string(),
      country: joi.string().uppercase().length(2)
    })
      .when('role_type', {
        is: 'org', // When role_type is "org" the address props become required
        then: {
          postal_code: joi.required(),
          country: joi.required()
        }
      })
  }
};

var data = {
  role_type: 'org',
  info: {address: {country: 'AF'}}
};

joi.assert(data, schema);
```

Unfortunately, the code above yields no errors. Why?

Tested on both joi v6 and the latest v10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one [can't reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options) parent object data:

> References cannot point up the object tree, only to sibling keys, but they can point to their siblings' children

A simplest workaround is to move the `.when()` one level up, so that joi would (deep) merge two `info` subschemas

```
var schema = {
  role_type: joi.string(),
  info: joi.object({
    address: joi.object({
      postal_code: joi.string(),
      country: joi.string().uppercase().length(2)
    })
  })
    .when('role_type', {
      is: 'org',
      then: joi.object({
        address: joi.object({
          postal_code: joi.required(),
          country: joi.required()
        })
      })
    })
};
```